# How to implement caching for static files in Angular 4

Tags: angular, caching, build, angular-cli

Using Angular 4, I want to achieve caching like in Angular 6 and above, which have the configuration below in angular.json file:

```
"production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
```

How can I achieve the same in Angular 4?

Comment: Upgrade? I think that was part of switching the build tooling over to Bazel, it's not something you can set in a config file.

Comment: no i dont want to upgrade angular version, how could i achieve caching .. in ang6 the static files are disk cached implicitly  but in ang4 it does not

Comment: Then I don't think you can, if you're not willing to upgrade you have to accept that you won't get new features either.